# Enforce Content Security Policy on old browsers

Tags: http-headers, content-security-policy

I'm currently testing out some content security policies for my React project. I am using a web config to add the custom headers as I'm hosting in IIS.

This all works well in Chrome etc but doesn't have any effect in older browsers such as IE11, as they don't support 99% of CSPs

What is the point if I can just bypass CSPs by using an old browser? Or am I missing some way of enforcing these rules, even for old browsers?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of CSPs is not to protect against malicious browser users, it's to protect against malicious or buggy websites. ([This article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/10/content-security-policy/) has some example attacks that CSPs are designed to mitigate.) Such attackers have no control over what browser a given person uses, so they can't use old browsers to "bypass" CSP protections.

Answer (score 0):

"bypass CSPs" does not means that somebody can hack your web page. It just means that user used obsolete browser is vulnerable to XSS (XSS it's a third-party action). It's user's decision, and you cen do nothing. Also users can use some browsers plugins to remove the CSP header with the same result in modern browsers.

However you can do you best to protect even users with obsolete browsers. Additionally to CSP header, use [X-XSS-Protection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection) header, IE supports it since IE 8.
Additionally you can publish [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header to prevent clickjacking, IE supports it.

But if your application works with some sensitive/financial data, perhaps the best solution is to prohibit the use of outdated browsers or warn the visitor that he is using an outdated browser and bears all responsibility of that.